# How to add words in aspell dictionary?

Tags: bash, livecode, aspell

I am using aspell in my application for spell checking. I don't have any idea about how to add words in aspell. Is it any way to add words

Comment: This question is definitely not a general question about computing hardware and software. It is a LiveCode programming question and should not be closed.

Answer (score 6):

To add words you feed in a list. If the word has a asterisk at the front it is added to the current dictionary. If there is a single line with a hash then the newly added words are saved to the users personal dictionary and then can be used through out the system.

```
echo "*WORD\n#" | aspell -a
```

There are multiple things you can do in relation to adding words to your dictionary and you can read about them [here.](http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-A-Pipe.html)

Comment: In LiveCode, that would be: `get shell("echo" && quote & "*WORD\n#" & quote && "| aspell -a")`

Comment: it's shows an error                                                                                                                          @(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707)
Error: The word "WORD\n#" is invalid. The character '\' (U+5C) may not appear in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 3):

To add a new word newword, do:

```
echo -e "*newword\n#" | aspell -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Songy's example `echo "*WORD\n#" | aspell -a` worked for me for a single word.  I was able to add text file (input.txt) containing a list of words using this command:

```
cat input.txt | while read word; do echo -e "*${word}\n#" | aspell -a; done
```